# Pass enum class as a parameter of constructor

Tags: c++11, enums

```
enum class EmployeeType {Employee, Manager, Sales, Unknown};

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee() = delete;
    Employee(const Employee&) = delete;
    Employee& operator=(const Employee&) = delete;
    Employee& operator=(Employee&&) = delete;

    Employee(Employee&&) = default;

    explicit Employee(EmployeeType type);
}
```

When I write in main():

```
Employee e1(EmployeeType::Manager);
```

or

```
Employee e2(Employee(EmployeeType::Manager));
```

it works fine.
When I write like this:

```
Employee e3({});
Employee e4(EmployeeType{});
Employee e5(EmployeeType(123));
```

compiler compiles it. But I want to forbid it using c++ keywords or using something else. I don't know how. **I want to permit only this:**

```
Employee e6(EmployeeType::Employee);
Employee e7(EmployeeType::Manager);
Employee e8(EmployeeType::Sales);
Employee e9(EmployeeType::Unknown);
Employee e10(Employee(EmployeeType::Employee));
Employee e11(Employee(EmployeeType::Manager));
Employee e12(Employee(EmployeeType::Sales));
Employee e13(Employee(EmployeeType::Unknown));
```

**How can I do it?**

I use g++ 5.4.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I write code in Qt Creator 4.1.0 with enabled C++11 in pro-file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent `Employee e3({});` by declaring an `initializer_list` constructor. This is always preferred when the initializer is a braced list:

```
Employee(std::initializer_list<int>) = delete;
```

The template type doesn't really matter.

However it is not possible to prevent a caller casting some value to `EmployeeType` and then providing that as constructor argument.

Comment: What does assigning delete to a constuctor do?

Comment: @HSchmale it means there will be a compilation error if the code would have invoked that constructor

Comment: M.M, thank you, with initializer_list now it works well!